# Where does jruby install with the official installer in mac

Tags: macos, installation

I downloaded the mac version of [jruby](http://jruby.org.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/1.6.7.2/JRuby-1.6.7.2.dmg).
After installing it doesn't show up in the path. I'm new to mac and don't know where it is installed.

I'm running Mac OS 10.6.8.

Comment: As a note to followers, jruby doesn't appear to offer the "one click distro" for OS X anymore :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JRuby should automatically be available as `jruby` on your command line. Eventually restart your Terminal.

Its framework is installed to:

```
/Library/Frameworks/JRuby.framework
```

Therefore, its binary is in:

```
/Library/Frameworks/JRuby.framework/Versions/Current/bin/jruby
```

If it doesn't work, manually add the following to your PATH, for example in `~/.bash_profile` or `.profile`, whatever you use):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/JRuby.framework/Versions/Current/bin
```

Comment: Thanks this fixes it. the installer had automatically created the `.profile` file but my zshrc didn't source it.

Comment: This is still an issue in jruby 1.7.4.